# Rails & Active Record: Get a collection of All Users' most recent book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A User has_many Books. My goal is to render all Users' most recent book. I figure an easy way to accomplish this would be to get the first book for each user_id.

Is there a clean Railsy way to get this?

Comment: What means "first book"? Book with lowest `id` or it is related to a kind of interaction between users and books?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. first book means User.books.first AKA book with highest CREATED_AT

Comment: So I want to get User.each {|u| u.books.first } but I want minimal queries

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you :)

`Book.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).select("max(created_at)")`

First, we group all books by their `user_id`. Then, we select only the most recent one from each group.